# Clone.Vm using Vestris.VMWareLib

Tags: c#, powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm trying to clone a Virtual Machine  using **VVMWareLib**.

The code I'm using is the following

```
using System;
using Vestris.VMWareLib;

namespace QsBuild.Blocks.VmWare
{
    public interface ICloneVmBlock
    {
        void CloneVm(string filename);
    }

    internal class CloneVmBlock : ICloneVmBlock
    {
        public void CloneVm(string filename, string destConfigPathName)
        {
            var virtualhost = new VMWareVirtualHost();

            virtualhost.ConnectToVMWareVIServer("IpServer", "UserName", "Password");

            var vm =
                virtualhost.Open(
                    filename);

            Console.WriteLine("vm is open");
            vm.Clone(VMWareVirtualMachineCloneType.Full, "[datastore1] QA20 (Ubuntu Linux)/QA20.vmx", 150);
        }
    }
}
```

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Vestris.VMWareLib.dll but >was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Failed to clone virtual machine:
>   cloneType="Full" destConfigPathName="[VMQA]" timeoutInSeconds=150

When I click on more detail I get message

> {"The operation is not supported"}
>
> StackTrace
>
> at
>   Vestris.VMWareLib.VMWareVirtualMachine.Clone(VMWareVirtualMachineCloneType
>   cloneType, String destConfigPathName, Int32 timeoutInSeconds)    at
>   QsBuild.Blocks.VmWare.CloneVmBlock.CloneVm(String filename) in
>   d:\TFS\Trunk\Tools\DevEnv\QsBuild\QsBuild\Blocks\VmWare\CloneVmBlock.cs:line
>   24    at QsBuild.Tests.Blocks.VmWare.CloneVmBlockTests.CloneVm() in
>   d:\TFS\Trunk\Tools\DevEnv\QsBuild\QsBuild.Tests\Blocks\VmWare\CloneVmBlockTests.cs:line
>   16

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers here....

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/510480